# Hbase exception org/apache/commons/configuration/Configuration not found

Tags: hbase

I am new to hbase trying to make it work with java . i tried the following code it gives an exception please help.

```
package com.bee.searchlib.test;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HColumnDescriptor;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HTableDescriptor;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        HBaseAdmin admin = null;
        try {
            // HBaseAdmin is where all the "DDL" like operations take place in
            // HBase
            admin = new HBaseAdmin(config);
        } catch (MasterNotRunningException e) {
            throw new Exception(
                    "Could not setup HBaseAdmin as no master is running, did you start HBase?...");
        }

        if (!admin.tableExists("testTable")) {
            admin.createTable(new HTableDescriptor("testTable"));

            // disable so we can make changes to it
            admin.disableTable("testTable");

            // lets add 2 columns
            admin.addColumn("testTable", new HColumnDescriptor("firstName"));
            admin.addColumn("testTable", new HColumnDescriptor("lastName"));

            // enable the table for use
            admin.enableTable("testTable");

        }

        // get the table so we can use it in the next set of examples
        HTable table = new HTable(config, "testTable");
    }
}
```

excepion:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/configuration/Configuration
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.DefaultMetricsSystem.<init>(DefaultMetricsSystem.java:37)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.DefaultMetricsSystem.<clinit>(DefaultMetricsSystem.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UgiInstrumentation.create(UgiInstrumentation.java:51)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:209)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:177)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.isSecurityEnabled(UserGroupInformation.java:229)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.KerberosName.<clinit>(KerberosName.java:83)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:202)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:177)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.isSecurityEnabled(UserGroupInformation.java:229)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:428)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:414)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Methods.call(Methods.java:37)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.User.call(User.java:586)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.User.callStatic(User.java:576)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.User.access$400(User.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.User$SecureHadoopUser.<init>(User.java:393)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.User$SecureHadoopUser.<init>(User.java:388)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.User.getCurrent(User.java:139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionKey.<init>(HConnectionManager.java:412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.getConnection(HConnectionManager.java:182)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.<init>(HBaseAdmin.java:98)
    at com.bee.searchlib.test.Test.main(Test.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.configuration.Configuration
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 27 more
```

Libraries in build path
hadoop-core-1.0.0.jar
hbase-0.92.1.jar
log4j-1.2.16.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the `commons-configuration-x.x.jar` to your build path. You can find it under `$HADOOP_HOME/lib`. Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to jar Files. Add `commons-logging- version.jar`It worked for me