# What is the correct classpath in Hortonworks 2.2 sandbox for the org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration class file?

Tags: hbase, hortonworks-data-platform

I am using the Hortonworks 2.2 Sandbox and using the following class files for an Hbase program:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.*
```

In order to compile this standard program, I am using javac as follows:

```
 javac -cp "$PATH:/usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-2041/hbase/lib/*:/usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-2041/hadoop/lib/*" HbaseLoader.java
```

However, I am getting an error:

```
"class file for org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration not found"
```

I have tried different classpaths for this class file, such as

```
/usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-2041/hadoop/lib/*
```

And

```
/usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-2041/hadoop-yarn/lib/*
```

And

```
/usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-2041/hadoop-hdfs/lib*
```

And

```
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib
```

But no luck.

I have seen similar questions being asked here: https://2scompliment.wordpress.com/2013/12/11/running-hbase-java-applications-on-hortonworks-hadoop-sandbox-2-x-with-yarn/
and
[Hbase exception org/apache/commons/configuration/Configuration not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954412/hbase-exception-org-apache-commons-configuration-configuration-not-found)

But many answers give non-HWKS Sandbox solutions.

**This is the exception I get:**

```
HbaseLoader.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(inputFile);
    ^
  symbol:   class Scanner
  location: class HbaseLoader
HbaseLoader.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(inputFile);
                     ^
  symbol:   class Scanner
  location: class HbaseLoader
2 errors
```

I am using Hbase version: 0.98.4.2.2.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing similar issue while working with hbase.You can try following option.

java -cp .:$(hbase classpath):$(hadoop classpath)  HbaseLoader.java

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks that helped solve most of it. It wont find the Scanner class 
"org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan" though. Any clues on where this class file might be? It should be in $(hbase classpath) but based on the error I am getting, it is not.

Comment: It should be there in your hbase classpath. Can you paste exception? What is the version of your hbase?

Comment: are you trying to use ResultScanner because Scanner class is present in java not in hbase?

Comment: Nice catch. That is what was happening... all I needed to do was run with import java.util.Scanner. Feeling so silly right now :p